# How to overcome this "Error; Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'x' ; Another type of declaration exists '"

Tags: c#, .net

I have no clue how to deal with this error, I tried so many times and changed the class name as well, but its not working:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That will help other members to understand your 

problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The class name News is used somewhere else as well. Change the name to say NewsClass

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 classes in your solution with the same name "News" and namespace "App4" - This is not allowed.

Its probably the form News.xaml.cs. Solution is to change one of the classnames or namespaces.